# How do I compile JVM assembly code into bytecode?

Tags: java, assembly, jvm, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

If I ran `javap -c ASM.class > ASM.java` to get the assembly code, how would I recompile this back into JVM bytecode?

Comment: first try not using `.java` for assembly java as it is confusion. i use `.jasm`

Comment: @ColeJohnson Thanks. I didn't know about that file extension.

Comment: as a developer, you can label your files whatever you want. There is no standard. I just chose jasm to differentiate it between .asm and chose j because it is like nasm, masm, etc. (??? ASeMbler)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Jasmin](http://jasmin.sourceforge.net/) is an assembler for Java bytecodes.  However, I don't know whether it can cope with the output from javap.

---

**UPDATE**

The Jasmin documentation says this about `javap` output:

> Sun does provide a javap program which can print the assembly code in a class file. However, the javap output is inappropriate for use as an assembler format. It is designed to be read by a person, not to be parsed by an assembler, so it has a number of omissions and drawbacks.

On the basis of this, I'd say there is little chance of finding an assembler that takes `javap` output as its input.